# How to call CDS view generated Odata service from UI5 app

Tags: sapui5, hana

When oData Query is set to `true` in CDS View .

Automatically oData Service is generated on the base of my CDS view.

Please find the below answer for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Cds View Name : `Z_EXAMPLE`

When oData Query set to true in CDS

Automatically oData Service is generated on the base of my CDS view as `Z_EXAMPLE_CDS`

From UI5 side code to call CDS query

```
var sUrl = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/Z_EXAMPLE_CDS/";
var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(sUrl, {
  json: true,
  loadMetadataAsync: true
});
oDataModel.read("/EntiySetName/Results", {
  filters: [],
  urlParameters: {
    "$select": "field1,field2,field3",
  },
  success: function(oData, response) {}
});
```